# How do I use Ruby to connect to a SQLite3 database outside of Rails as a scripting language

Tags: ruby, sqlite

Hi Im using Ruby as a scripting language. Not for web development, but to connect to a local database on my computer and manipulate it.

Id like to know how I can connect. Do I need to download/import tools? What do I need to get started?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to install the `sqlite3` gem:

```
gem install sqlite3
```

You can then use the library in your code. Here's an example, adapted from the [project's `README.rdoc` file](https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby):

```
require 'sqlite3'

# Open a SQLite 3 database file
db = SQLite3::Database.new 'file.db'

# Create a table
result = db.execute <<-SQL
  CREATE TABLE numbers (
    name VARCHAR(30),
    val INT
  );
SQL

# Insert some data into it
{ 'one' => 1, 'two' => 2 }.each do |pair|
  db.execute 'insert into numbers values (?, ?)', pair
end

# Find some records
db.execute 'SELECT * FROM numbers' do |row|
  p row
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have knowledge on Rails apps, you would like to have those Models features on your app. And you can have it, using the ActiveRecord gem. Unless the data in your app is really simple and easy to query you should tink about use active record, or something like it.

Here are some links

- http://www.agileadvisor.com/2008/01/using-activerecord-outside-rails.html
- http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3097